# Symfony API: Error from file that does not even exist

Tags: php, docker, symfony, api-platform.com

I have another matter I feel is getting way over my head. At first you'll think, well..That's a very common error which is resolved within a few seconds. Well.. no. Before I start, let it be known that I have a PHP Container in Docker with Symfony, using the api-platform framework.

The error:
`NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Entity\Greeting' not found in /srv/api/var/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__AppEntityGreeting.php:8 Stack trace: /srv/api/var/cache/prod/App_KernelProdContainer.preload.php(428): require_once()`

Well. Looks easy. However. The whole `App\Entity\Greeting` doesn't exist at all. Why? Because it is a standard template file of api-platform, which we are not using. The project is not a new one, it already exists. I pulled it from our Repository, and there is no mention at all in our code. Nowhere. I don't know where it's called from.

Deleting the container didn't work. Repulling and then starting the container again to let it reinstall everything didn't help. I'm not sure what's up here. I reinstalled and even completely reinstalled docker and tried again. Even using an old backup of the code didn't work.

I'm not sure if this is a PHP error, or something container related. PHP Exits though. It's just not clear at all, since the file couldn't exist in this case.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the symfony cache as well as trashing and reinstalling the vendor directory?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes, I tried. Sadly to no avail.

Comment: Next, try `cd`'ing the project directory and running `find . -type f -name "*.php" | xargs grep -Hns "Greeting"` to see if you can find the specific file that is referencing it

Comment: @ChrisHaas I can't. The thing is this: It is in an container, and when I try to start the container PHP will start, but exits pretty fast afterwards with the above error. This completely exits the whole container, meaning I get thrown out before I'm there.

Comment: Yuck, sorry to hear that. I must admit, I haven't dug really deep into containers for reasons such as this. I know there's some really smart people out there that can probably help, hopefully. Although you have a PHP problem, I think you really need to find a way to change your container's startup so that it doesn't automatically stop on failure, maybe rephrase the question that way? Are you priming Symfony's cache on boot up?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using redis as a cache, try to clear the redis DB:

```
redis-cli FLUSHDB
```